# How to manupulate fetched data with another data in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new Node.js. My problem is I want to fetch data from one collection `User` and also I had collected data in another collection `Friend`

```
    User.find({_id: {'$ne':user_id }}).then(data1 => {
        Friend.find({user_id: user_id }).then(data2 => {
         console.log(data1)
         console.log(data2)
        });
      });
```

Now I want to filter when the collection `Friend` has `user_id` attribute is not match with the  `User` collections `_id`

How to manipulate the data after fetching from MongoDB?

Comment: so `data2.filter(friend => data1.every(({user_id}) => user_id !== friend.user_id))` is that what you mean?

Comment: Can you explain this code sir?

Comment: it filters `data2` including only those whose `user_id` is not a `user_id` in `data1` ... assuming `data2` and `data1` are Arrays ... you use the word "collection", so I guessed they were Arrays because you used the word `filter`... can you show an example of data1 and data2 - then I *may* be able to write an answer, with explanation

Comment: Data1 is collected from database,, its response from database

Comment: Which underlying database?  Looks like Mongo, but just checking.  Depending on the DB, this might be doable in the DB in one round trip rather than in the application code.

Comment: Yes, I know where it comes from ... but I can't **see** what it looks like can I, which is what I asked for ... it could be an array, or an object, or a string for all I know

Comment: now the filter could be as simple as `data2.filter(({ user_id }) => data1.every(({ _id }) => user_id !==  _id))`

Comment: @learner - try using Kien's code with the updated filter in the above comment

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you use `async/await` for cleaner code.

```js
async function filter(user_id) {
   let data1 = await User.find({_id: {'$ne':user_id }}).toArray();
   let data2 = await Friend.find({user_id: user_id }).toArray();
   let filteredData = data2.filter(friend => data1.every(({user_id}) => user_id !== friend.user_id));
   console.log(filteredData );
}
```

Comment: Sorry sir one updated in my code, From User table it `_id` instead of `user_id`.I had tested but it's not working, I think the problem in my code

Comment: see, @learner that doesn't help ... how about posting, in the question, the result of YOUR CODE, i.e something is sent to the console ... so huzzah, you've got something you can post to show what your requests are receiving

Comment: From user collection, I had to fetch all the users data and also in friend table I will collect all the data which will friend with that user. Now I want to display the remaining user which means I want to show `add  friend ` suggestions

Comment: yes, you keep describing how your getting the data, and what you want to do with it ... without showing the data content ... it's like 20 questions ... do you understand what I'm asking you for>?